# Difference between an Array and a List

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have values from 0-300, I must only project values >50 and <200,
I can do this with both List and Array but I am forced to use a Array for this task,
what is the exact difference between the two in terms on ability?

I was able to do it with both List and Array but still confused between the use of list if you can do the same thing with an Array

Comment: In the world of Python we have lists. A commonly used module *numpy* has arrays that have quite different functional capability than pure Python lists. Check out the *numpy* documentation

Comment: In a broader sense, Python lists are in fact arrays.  But for some reason, Python calls them lists.  Further, the numpy package has its own arrays which it calls arrays.  So, in a broad sense, if you want to use an array, lists qualify.  But in a specific sense, if you want the actual array type, you need to use numpy.